# Getter return type as Optional

Tags: java

I have the following dilemma.

My application is using external ReST service which returns JSON:

**Publication**

```
{
   "title" : "some title",
   "tag" : "some tag",
   "date" : some_date,
    ... (more)
}
```

I have DTO to map this:

```
public class PublicationDto {
    String title;
    String tag;
    Date date;
}
```

Assume that it is lombok annotated and has getters and setters.
Now, the date can be optional. It can be in JSON or not.
So in mapped DTO date can be null.

My dilemma is, if I should do null checks later in the code that is processing `PublicationDto`, or should I do some tricks with `Optional`. For example I can override `getDate()` method in `PublicationDto` to return `Optional<Date>`:

```
public Optional<Date> getDate();
```

What is the best practice in such cases?

Comment: custom getter returning the `Optional<Date>`.

Comment: Might also depend what you use to de-serialize into your POJO. For instance Jackson has ways to make a property optional, and even use a default value.

Comment: @Mena thanks for you idea I search for Optional with jackson and read http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-optional this.Then the json is change to different. I think best solution is custom getter for Optional

Comment: @janith1024 no worries. I don't think you actually need an `Optional` if you're using Jackson though. Having the property annotated with an optional value flag and the default value should probably suffice.

Answer (score 0):

There’s no best practice in JSON Java deserialization that says you’ll be hanged if you don’t use `Optional`. Java is not Scala. It depends on what you plan to do with the missing value. Replacing null check with an empty check doesn’t buy you anything, except for may be bragging rights that you’re writing more “modern” code. However, if you’re going to perform further operations on the date, like falling back to a default value for example, and further formatting it for display, then having an `Optional` can be useful to do the functional type chaining.